# Replicated record triggers multiple times for a single update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Setup SQL Server 2012 tables replicated from another server; 
Update/Insert trigger (on replicated table A) triggers multiple times on a single record update;

Content of trigger is:

```
BEGIN
IF (UPDATE(AdmitDate) AND UPDATE(AdmitTime)) OR (UPDATE(DischargeDate) AND UPDATE(DischargeTime)) --Check to see if any of the relevant conditions have changed
BEGIN --This is automatically true for an insert assumed they were originally null
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        -- Get patient's chartnumber through the inserted record
        SELECT  @ChartNumber = i.ChartNumber FROM inserted i
        SET @DatabaseName=Convert(Varchar(100),DB_NAME())

        SET @user=CURRENT_USER;
        SET @message = 'ChartNumber[' + @ChartNumber+'], Database Name:[' +@DatabaseName+']';
        Execute [sp_APP-Log-Entry]  @user, '5000', 0, 0,  'Trigger on AB_Abstract', '26', @message; -------------------------------------------------------

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        --IF XACT_STATE() = -1 ROLLBACK;  -- REPLICATION WILL DIE ANYWAY ON ANY ERROR. 
        INSERT INTO X_HUDB.dbo.[App-Response_log]
            VALUES (CONVERT(sysname, CURRENT_USER), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), 
                    ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), getdate())
    END CATCH
END
```

END

How could this happen? I realize there are UPDATE conditions but it should indicate that [sp_APP-Log-Entry] gets called fewer times but right now it calls between 2 and 7 times for a replicated record, but only ONCE if I update multiple fields with an update query using a non-replicated table from a different database instance.

(No errors I can see or it would break the replication)

Comment: `inserted` can contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. `SELECT  @ScalarVariable = column FROM inserted` is a broken concept. Also, you should avoid naming stored procedures starting with `sp_`. Finally, on topic to your question, have you considered marking your trigger as `NOT FOR REPLICATION`?

Answer (score 0):

The record was updated multiple times (within a few milliseconds) in the source system by multiple business rules.  It turns out that the replication was working a little too perfectly.

Maybe Murphy needed to meet Occam.

Nevertheless I would steer away from an email or complex logic linked to a trigger in future its only that the system being replicated was a package.  Polling every minute on an inserted/deleted table with some metadata from the trigger would be preferable to real time given the tradeoffs of the inherent instability of a bad design pattern.